# else if statement is not registered in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am having an issue with an 'if else if' function in jQuery. The last two statements of my code are not detected at all, so nothing happens when i expect a page to load. Does anybody know what is wrong with this?

```
function pageloader() {
    var position = $('#slideInner').css('marginLeft');
    if (position >= '-936px') {
        // load the page contents 
        $('#blogs').load('pagetwo.html #blog');
        // hide the loading box 
        loadoff();
        $('#portfolio').empty();
    }
    else if (position = '-1872px') {
        $('#portfolio').load('pagethree.html #homepage');
        loadoff();
        $('#blogs').empty();
    }
    else if (position = '-2808px') {
        $('#contact').load('pagefour.html #homepage');
        // hide the loading box 
        loadoff();
    }
    else {
        alert('all posibilities exausted');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `if` conditions are wrong.

Replace `=` by `==` in both these lines

```
if ( position == '-1872px')

if ( position == '-2808px')
```

If it was a typo fine, otherwise FYI

```
if(postion = 'anything') //will always pass the if clause
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly i cant believe i let that slide past me, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The operator `>` or `<` should be used to compare numbers not strings. Also, when doing comparisons use `==` not `=` which is the assignment operator and will almost always evaluate to true. In your case you'll want to convert the position to a number first:

```
// position is now a Number
var position = parseInt($('#slideInner').css('marginLeft'));

if ( position >= -936) {
  // do something
} else if ( position == -1872) {
  // do something
}else if ( position == -2808){
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as Shankar points out, you need the "equivalence" operator (==).  A single (=) assigns to a variable, which always evaluates to true.

I'd also rewrite because of the conditions you are checking to make it more readable.  Like this:

```
function pageloader()
{
var position = $('#slideInner').css('marginLeft');

if (position >= '-936px')
{
    // load the page contents 
    $('#blogs').load('pagetwo.html #blog');
    // hide the loading box 
    loadoff();
    $('#portfolio').empty();
    return;
}

if (position == '-1872px')
{
    $('#portfolio').load('pagethree.html #homepage');

    loadoff();
    $('#blogs').empty();
    return;
}

if (position == '-2808px')
{
    $('#contact').load('pagefour.html #homepage');
    // hide the loading box 
    loadoff();
    return;
}

alert('all posibilities exausted');
 }
```

Comment: I don't think having 3 different places from which the function returns makes it more readable. Readability, is irrelevant to the question, so your answer doesn't add anything new to @Shankar's answer.